# Assambly.GetTypes() выдает исключение при добавлении в плагин пакетов Asp.NetCore.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, сборка, плагин

Решил реализовать плагинную систему с использованием ASP .NET Core MVC. Хост приложение представляет из себя .NET Core WPF шаблон, но также в нем запускается WebHost. Плагин представляет из себя билиотеку классов .NET Core .dll. И все замечательно работало, пока я не добавил MVC. В хосте MVC работает, а в плагине успел только добавить Asp.NetCore.Mvc NuGet и все сломалось. Assambly.GetTypes() выдает исключение "Unable to load one or more of the requested types". Удаляю NuGet, опять все работает. Microsoft писали

> "Currently, plugins can't introduce new frameworks into the process.
> For example, you can't load a plugin that uses the
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework into an application that only uses
> the root Microsoft.NETCore.App framework. The host application must
> declare references to all frameworks needed by plugins."

Но у меня плагин не добавляет новых пакетов в процесс хоста. Не пойму что еще не так.
Вот код класса, который добавляет плагины(там половина кода взята с сайта Microsoft):

```
nternal static class PluginManager
{
    public static Dictionary<int, IPlugin> LoadedPlugins = new Dictionary<int, IPlugin>();

    static int id = 0;

    static string pluginDirectory = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Plugins\\netcoreapp3.1");
    static List<string> pluginPaths = new List<string>();

    static PluginManager()
    {
        LoadPlugins();
    }

    static void LoadPlugins()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(pluginDirectory))
        {
            pluginPaths.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(pluginDirectory + "\\", "*.dll"));
        }

        foreach (var path in pluginPaths)
        {
            Assembly assembly = LoadPlugin(path); //тут исключение, и кроме названия сборки ничего не грузится
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (Activator.CreateInstance(type) is IPlugin plugin)
                {
                    plugin.Id = id++;
                    LoadedPlugins.Add(plugin.Id, plugin);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static Assembly LoadPlugin(string path)
    {
        PluginLoadContext context = new PluginLoadContext(path);
        return context.LoadFromAssemblyName(new AssemblyName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)));
    }

    class PluginLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        private AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

        public PluginLoadContext(string pluginPath)
        {
            _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(pluginPath);
        }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(string unmanagedDllName)
        {
            string libraryPath = _resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath(unmanagedDllName);
            if (libraryPath != null)
            {
                return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(libraryPath);
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все. Разобрался. Это видимо ругался IIS-сервер В методе `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` класса плагина сделал вот так и все заработало:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(MyPlugin).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
    }
```

Я вообще готовое решение с плагинами нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722484/asp-net-core-mvc-2-1-mvc-views-in-plugin